# php how to redeclare class in a for loop

Tags: php, oop

Im using a library called [PDFmerger](https://pdfmerger.codeplex.com/) , naturally, it merges pdfs together. I wish to run a cron every night that builds these to have them ready for the next day. The issue is when I run the code after the first one it fails because it is attempting to redeclare the class.

The `for` statement...

```
            foreach ($pdfs_to_build as $pdf) {

                // do stuff

                $this->merge_pdfs($pdf['pdf_id']);

            }
```

And my pdf merging code that gets ran in the loop...

```
$pdf = new PDFMerger;

$pdf->addPDF(DIR_BOOKS.$book_path.'/static-pages/page-1.pdf', '1'); 
$pdf->addPDF(DIR_FINAL_PDFS.$pdf_id.'/custom-page-1.pdf','1'); 
$pdf->addPDF(DIR_BOOKS.$book_path.'/static-pages/page-2.pdf', '1'); 

$pdf->merge('file', DIR_FINAL_PDFS.$pdf_id.'/final-build-'.$pdf_id.'.pdf');
```

Error after the first 1 is complete and we've onto the next one...

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class PDFMerger in /var/www/example/pdfmerger/PDFMerger.php on line 24

Im wondering is there a workaround for this?

Comment: You are missing parentheses: `$pdf = new PDFMerger();`

Comment: try unsetting the class object at the end of the file...

Comment: You probably have `include pdfmerger.php` inside `merge_pdfs`. A simple workaround is to put it globally.

Comment: The semicolon should come after the parentheses right? new PDFMerger();

Comment: @Zach Brackets are optional, if there's no constructor, or you needn't pass any arguments to it, they can be left out (`new stdClass;` is fine). The error seems to me like OP is including a class definition file multiple times, or has a `class PDFMerger {}` at various points in his code

Comment: @bcesars: They're not required. `$x = new stdClass;` is just as valid as `$x = new stdClass();` The brackets are not the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't that you're calling `new PDFMerger` twice, that's perfectly acceptable.  The problem is that the file:

```
/var/www/example/pdfmerger/PDFMerger.php
```

Is being `include`'d (or otherwise executed) twice, which has on line 24:

```
class PDFMerger {
```

That is what is triggering your error, that class has already been declared.  Figure out why that file is being included twice and your error will clear up.

Comment: `require_once` is a good choice. It is bad design to include/require files that declares class/functions/constants etc, in loops. In this case OP is lucky that he's using php which is sucky enough not to allow classes to be overwritten with the same name, hence the error.

Comment: @chelmertz: A decent autoloader would be even better. `require_once` in a loop is just ugly in so many ways (and unreliable, if the value you loop over was empty, the class definition will not be required, and you'll soon end up with code littered with `require_once` statements, each time checking what files were included, and which weren't. The best choice still is an autoloader that simply `require`'s the files

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. That won't fail. However, not listed in what you posted, you are including `PDFMerger.php`.
Probably by having the `include 'PDFMerger.php';` shown at https://pdfmerger.codeplex.com/ run inside the loop.

Just move that line out of the loop and/or change the `include` to `include_once`.

Comment: `include_once` or `require_once` would fix this issue, but it'd be best to leave it out of the loop (each `include_once` statement _will_ check if the file has been included yet -> overhead). Better still would be to use an autoloader...

Comment: Personally, I would move it out of the loop **and** change it to a `require_once`, but I also wanted to hint that `include_once` can be a solution.